# Is it a good practice to rename global variables and methods for minification

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have used `document` and `setAttribute` several times throughout the code.

Now, if I declare these in the beginning,

```js
const _document     = document,
      _setAttribute = 'setAttribute';
```

and then later in the script, use them as,

```
_document.querySelector('.class')[_setAttribute]('data-something', '');
```

will it be fine, or will it have some flaws?

Comment: Firstly, there is no benefit at all in doing this. Minifying is so insignificant and can be done automatically before publishing. Secondly, it just makes your code unnecessarily more difficult to understand and maintain for other people.

Comment: "*Minifying is so insignificant*" I don't think so. I am able to further reduce the size by around 10% with this implementation and wanted to know if it is okay to do it this way or not. And as pointed out by you, one issue could be that the code would become difficult for others to understand.

Comment: Yes running this though tearser shows that it will minify quite a bit if you have frequient access to the aliased methods. The reason why utilities such as tearser won't minify this without aliasing seems to be performance related though. So while you gain some time during download/parse you might loose some during execition. https://github.com/terser/terser/issues/590 I myself is in the same lane as @JavaScript here though, maintainability is almost always more important then a small size or performance gain.

Comment: Can you provide any references to JavaScript [style guiles](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html) or [best practices](https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices) that recommend this?  The only reason I can think to do it would be at the module level if it helped simplify the code and make it more readable, but not to save space.

Comment: Comparing the size of the raw file doesn't mean much. If your server is configured correctly the data will be gzipped anyway before going through the pipes. Gzip is actually very good with repeating patterns, so you could very well have the same amount of data being transferred in both cases.

Comment: @Yogi It does save a good amount of space but I get the whole point of this discussion now, and as Kaiido has added - "*Gzip is actually very good with repeating patterns*", it just make more sense to NOT do what I was trying to do.

Comment: You could always stick that whole call to setAttribute in a function so long as you use the function everywhere then the function name will get minified saving more space

Answer (score 1):

IMO saving a couple bytes shouldn't really matter to you... Today's internet access is very fast and there are so many tools that can do it for you after you code, you are only slowing your development efforts by doing this. Code will be harder to read, harder to maintain. Also between `_document` and `document` you are using up more characters than the original variable... To what use?

Also note that your file can be served gzipped which will have a great impact on your file size.

Unless you are using a good http/2 server, https negotiation will likely take up a good chunk of the loading time for a medium sized file. I timed my bank's website, to serve a 44KB javascript file, it took 347ms*. From these 347ms, it took only 117 to download the file. The rest was mostly finding the server (DNS) and negotiating the connection (SSL). Shaving 50% off of the file size would hypothetically remove 59ms of download time. Putting the request length at 288 an effective 17% faster request.

[image]

All in all, this kind of optimization will certainly hurt your development efforts. Since there are already great tools to minimize at the end, there is no immediate need to harm your productivity by doing it yourself. Rules in optimizations are measure, measure, measure. So once your application/code is done, test its download speed, and performance. Then see which one you want to optimize and focus there.

*I'm in the train on my PC using internet that my phone shares through bluetooth.

[EDIT]
Also, if you want to keep maintainability and reduce code size, you *could* create utility function, like if your example is used quite a lot it might help.

```
function setAttributeSelector(selector,attribute,value){
    document.querySelector('.class').setAttribute('data-something', '');
}

//and use it
setAttributeSelector('.class','data-something','');
```

But do this only if it makes sense to your codebase.

Comment: `_document` will be replaced by a single letter, say `d` after using a minification tool... But I get the point, maintainability > size reduction. It was becoming an underscore hell for me for real.